# Preload AdMob Interstitial ad in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In order to implement a preload ad in the Main Activity and then use it in other activity, I am trying to follow that [example](https://www.codenari.com/android/preload-admob-interstitial-ad-and-send-to-another-activity/) which is in Java. When i converted the code for Kotlin I get the following error: [image: following error] . Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow my Interstitial implementation from my project following [this](https://github.com/ArcaDone/DodgeTheEnemies/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/arcadan/dodgetheenemies/fragments/GameWonFragment.kt) link.

In general, inside `OnActivityCreated` add the function `loadInterstitial()` :

```
private lateinit var interstitialAd: InterstitialAd

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
 ...
    loadInterstitial()
 ...
 }

private fun loadInterstitial() {
    interstitialAd = InterstitialAd(requireContext())
    interstitialAd.adUnitId = BuildConfig.interstitialAds
    interstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
}
```